# Разбить строку с использованием Regex

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

я пытаюсь разбить строку через пробелы, но не разбивать всё что заключено в скобки `()`

Данный код работает нормально для (a + b) * c * (x - y) ==>
(a + b),
*,
c,
*,
(x - y)

```
Regex.Matches(expression, @"[\(].+?[\)]|[^ ]+")
                                        .Cast<Match>()
                                        .Select(m => m.Value)
                                        .ToArray();
```

Но этот пример разбивается не так как я ожидаю...

```
(a * (x - y)) * c
```

Получается: (a * (x - y), ), *, с
Ожидается: (a * (x - y)), *, с

Я уже второй день ломаю голову, что бы правильно разбить, но никак не получается. Я думаю надо сделать что бы закрывающая скобка `[\)]` засчитывалась только если после нее нету такой же скобки без открывающей перед ней :-)

Но вот не могу написать такое выражение...

Comment: хм, регулярные выражения плохо подходят для разбора нерегулярных структур..

Comment: Тогда вам нужно для "(" прописывать исключение. Одно, или несколько.

Comment: А зачем вам это, собственно? Если вы хотите "приоритет" операций выставить, то есть готовые решения на c# "обратная польская запись", и даже на SO.

Comment: вот [этот ответ на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2110496) тут тоже подходит, там про html, но это не суть.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте "balanced construct":

```
Regex.Matches(s, @"(?x)
      \(                    # открывающая круглая скобка
      (?>                   # начало группы, которая находит... 
         [^()]+|            # 1+ символов, отличных от круглых скобок
         (?<o>)\(|          # открывающая круглая скобка (пустая строка добавляется в стек группы `o`)
         (?<-o>)\)          # закрывающая круглая скобка (пустая строка удаляется из стека группы `o`)
       )*                   #  повторить 0 и более раз
       (?(o)(?!))           # если в стеке группы `o` остались значения, отменить совпадение
      \)                    # закрывающая круглая скобка
     |                      # или
      [^\s()]+              # 1+ символов, отличных от пробельных и круглых скобок
     ")           
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%28%28%3F%3E%5B%5E%28%29%5D%2B%7C%28%3F%3Co%3E%29%5C%28%7C%28%3F%3C-o%3E%29%5C%29%29*%28%3F%28o%29%28%3F!%29%29%5C%29%7C%5B%5E%5Cs%28%29%5D%2B&i=%28a%20%2B%20b%29%20*%20c%20*%20%28x%20-%20y%29%0D%0A%28a%20*%20%28x%20-%20y%29%29%20*%20c), а [здесь демо C#](https://ideone.com/vWN4uP).

**Подробности**

- `\(` - открывающая круглая скобка
- `(?>` - начало группы, которая находит...

  - `[^()]+|` - 1+ символов, отличных от круглых скобок
  - `(?<o>)\(|` - открывающая круглая скобка (пустая строка добавляется в стек группы `o`)
  - `(?<-o>)\)` - закрывающая круглая скобка (пустая строка удаляется из стека группы `o`)
- `)*` - повторить 0 и более раз
- `(?(o)(?!))` - если в стеке группы `o` остались значения, отменить совпадение
- `\)` - закрывающая круглая скобка
- `|` - или
- `[^\s()]+` - 1+ символов, отличных от пробельных и круглых скобок.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что означает "o" - подскажите пожайлуста. Не вижу в стадарных описаниях это... Или "o" - это подстановочный идентификатор который задан в `<o>`?

Comment: @nick_n_a Это "техническая" именная захватывающая подмаска/группа, нужная для того чтобы "считать" открывающие и закрывающие круглые скобки.

Comment: +1, но это жесть-же! Как это потом поддерживать?

Comment: К слову, подобные расширения регулярных выражений превращают их в нечто отличное от "регулярных выражений".

Comment: @АндрейNOP Можно использовать `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhiteSpace`, чтобы добавить комментарии к регулярке. Ничего в ней сложного, если честно.

Comment: Для того, кто это писал, конечно нет ничего сложного. Для читателя же тут что то на эльфийском :)

Comment: @tym32167 Не, уши у меня обычные, человеческие...

Comment: Спасибо, как раз то что мне нужно. Отдельно спасибо за расшифровку :-)

Answer (score 2):

Если задача просто разбить строку по пробелам, то можно попробовать и без регулярок это сделать. Например так

```
IEnumerable<string> Split(string input)
{
    var counter = 0;
    var startPos = 0;
    List<string> parts = new List<string>();

    for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        var c = input[i];
        if (c == ' ' && counter == 0)
        {
            var len = i - startPos;
            if (len > 0)
            {
                parts.Add(input.Substring(startPos, len));
            }
            startPos = i+1;
        }
        if (c == '(') counter++;
        if (c == ')') counter--;        
    }

    var lastInd = input.Length;
    var lastLen = lastInd - startPos;
    if (lastLen > 0) parts.Add(input.Substring(startPos, lastLen ));

    return parts;
}
```

Да, кода больше, но имхо он понятней, чем регулярка, да и работает в теории побыстрее.

Вариант с ленивым вычислением. Пользоваться можно также, как первым вариантом.

```
IEnumerable<string> Split(string input)
{
    var counter = 0;
    var startPos = 0;   

    for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        var c = input[i];
        if (c == ' ' && counter == 0)
        {
            var len = i - startPos;
            if (len > 0)
            {                   
                yield return input.Substring(startPos, len);
            }
            startPos = i+1;
        }
        if (c == '(') counter++;
        if (c == ')') counter--;        
    }

    var lastInd = input.Length;
    var lastLen = lastInd - startPos;       
    if (lastLen > 0) yield return input.Substring(startPos, lastLen);
}
```

Comment: раз уж возвращаете `IEnumerable`, почему бы не сделать лениво (`yield`)? Изменений не много, а клиенту выгода (может быть), ну или он сам `.ToList()` при желании сделает.

Comment: @АндрейNOP добавил лени

Comment: Лига Лени одобряет!

Comment: Спасибо отличный и простой алгоритм, но я предпочел Regex (так как в учебных целях пишу апликуху).