# Регулярное выражение исключающее запятую в скобках

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть строки вот такого вида:

Бла(бла бла, бла бла, бла), Бла бла

Как я могу составить регулярку, что бы получить 2 совпадения:

Бла(бла бла, бла бла, бла)

Бла бла

Т.е запятая- это делитель в том случае, если он вне скобок.

Comment: Возможно `^([A-Z ](\x28[^\x29]\x29)?(,|$))`

Comment: не не получается..

Comment: Какую библиотеку регулярных выражений используете? Кстати, если что-то уже пробовали, добавьте в вопрос. Бывают в строке вложенные скобки?

Comment: Могут ли быть вложенные скобки?

Comment: Что насчёт более сложных примеров? "бла(бла (бла, бла бла, бла)"? "Бла(бла (бла), бла) бла, бла)"?

Comment: @yolosora, не встречал, но если можно, то хорошо бы предусмотреть.

Answer (score 0):

Если вложенные скобки учитывать не требуется, то у нас по сути 2 варианта:

- блок не содержит запятой и скобок: `[^,()]+`
- блок содержит любое количество символов, отличных от запятой, открывающая скобка, любое количество символов (в том числе и запятые [обратите внимание, этот блок сделан ленивым, для того чтобы он не поглотил всё до самой последней закрывающей скобки, он остановится перед самой первой встретившейся]), закрывающая скобка и   любое количество символов, отличных от запятой: `[^,]*\(.*?\)[^,]*`

Объединяем: `[^,]*\(.*?\)[^,]*|[^,()]+`

Если хотите подсчитывать вложенность скобок, то вам почти один в один подойдет [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/825742/218063)